# gulp-watch project does not working...

Tags: gulp, workflow, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I setup simple gulp workflow , but when i change the scss file it does not watch this file

my directory look like this.

```
project
   |-css
   |-js
   |-index.html
sass
   |-sass file here
gulpfile.js
```

look at the code...

```
gulp.task('sass',function(){
    gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({
      outputStyle: 'expanded'
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./project/css/'));
});

gulp.task('watch',function(){
    watch('./sass/**/*',['sass']);
});


gulp.task('server',function(){
    gulp.src('./project')
    .pipe(server({
        livereload: true,
        port: 3000,
        open: true
    }));
})

gulp.task('default',['server','watch','sass']);
```

what is the problem in this post, how can i fix this now?

Answer (score 0):

As we seen in your directory structure sass files are resides in sass/*.scss and you write './sass/**/*.scss
That may be an issue.

```
gulp.task('sass',function(){
    gulp.src('./sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({
      outputStyle: 'expanded'
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./project/css/'));
});

gulp.task('watch',function(){
    watch('./sass/*.scss',['sass']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a return statement to your 'sass' task

```
return gulp.src(stuff here)
```

Are you using gulp-livereload?  I would suggest following their usage example at

```
[gulp-livereload][1]
```

If you need help implementing that let us know.
I don't think their is anything wrong with your glob patterns as suggested in the answer from @Dipak.